# AVSpeechSynthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute seems like does not support Chinese

Tags: ios, localization, text-to-speech

When testing AVSpeechSynthesizer, `AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute` seems like does not support Chinese?

#### en-GB is OK:

```
let dst = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "It's pronounced 'tomato'")
let pronunciationKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute)
let range = NSString(string: "It's pronounced 'tomato'").range(of: "tomato")
// just test a joke
dst.setAttributes([pronunciationKey: "tə.do͡ʊ.ˈme͡ɪ"], range: range)
let result = dst.copy() as! NSAttributedString
utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: result)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

#### zh-CN is not OK

```
let dst = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "行人")
let pronunciationKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute)
let range = NSString(string: "行人").range(of: "行")
dst.setAttributes([pronunciationKey: "ˈme͡ɪ"], range: range)
//  I also tried "a"
//  dst.setAttributes([pronunciationKey: "a"], range: range)
let result = dst.copy() as! NSAttributedString
utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: result)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "zh-CN")
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Neither is zh-HK, zh-TW.

Perhaps there is some low level solution.

Comment: Just a suggestion, have a go with a different language e.g. French. If that doesn't work then perhaps there's a problem with both code blocks but the default voice is British, giving the illusion that the first code block is working. PS I often test with the string '1, 2, 3' because every language can use it i.e. instead of finding out new words for each language I want to try.

Comment: Have any solution?

Comment: u can try the solution of other platform., such as `https://www.xfyun.cn/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the WWDC 2018 Session "AVSpeechSynthesizer: Making iOS Talk",
IPA Notation is only available for the following languages:

en-US, en-AU, en-GB, de-DE, es-ES, es-MX, fr-CA, fr-FR, it-IT, ja-JP

I couldn't find any newer reference nor any other official documentation by Apple for AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute.

Sources:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/236/?time=424
https://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/